# std::string tries to free the wrong memory

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, stdstring, mysql++

I'm using the mysql++ library (v3.1.0) in a C++ project (compiled with GCC 4.8.1) in a linux environment, and have an ssqls object as a class member (`session_data`) of a class I have made (`Session`). Everything works fine, until an instance of my class comes to be destroyed, at which point a `std::string` object appears to try to free some memory it does not have, causing the kernel to step in. Below is part of the stack trace given by GDB after the failure.

```
#2  0x00c143ea in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x00c529d5 in __libc_message () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x00c58e31 in malloc_printerr () from /lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x00c5b571 in _int_free () from /lib/libc.so.6
#6  0x0810e43f in operator delete(void*) () at ../../../../gcc-4.8.1/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/del_op.cc:47
#7  0x081518eb in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) ()
    at /include/ext/new_allocator.h:110
#8  0x08151930 in std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose ()
    at /include/bits/basic_string.h:249
#9  0x0815199e in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() ()
    at /include/bits/basic_string.h:539
#10 0x080ac492 in session_data::~session_data() ()
    at sql_tables.h:80
#11 0x080ac537 in Session::~Session() ()
    at session.cpp:5
```

All these destructors appear to be created on-the-fly, in that I cannot set a breakpoint inside them because they don't exist according to GDB. Personally, I doubt it is an error in the code GCC has produced, which leaves me to assume I have "mistreated" the ssqls object in some way. So far my efforts to reproduce the error in a smaller project have failed, but if I do manage it I'll be certain to post that code here.
Really I'd like to know if anyone has any idea what goes on inside an ssqls object that may be causing this, in the meantime I'll keep trying to debug the issue.

EDIT with minimal code.
`session_data` is delcared entirely by ssqls macros, which I call like so:

```
sql_create_7(session_data,      4,7,    sql_varchar,    id,
                    sql_text,   last_ip,
                    sql_text,   last_user_agent,
                    sql_datetime,   expires,
                    sql_text,   account,
                    sql_text,   messages,
                    sql_text,   login_key)
```

The class `Session` fills the value of `session_data` by:

```
mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult res=query.store();
session=res[0];
```

(With `session_data session` being a class member, and `query` a mysql++ query object, which does have data from the database)
From time to time `session` may have its value changed by the line `session=tmp;` (where tmp is another session_data object). In all other cases variables within `session` are used by value, eg in `session.account`, so I don't think they should cause an issue. Hope this helps people a bit more.

Comment: My problem is I don't know which code is best. My whole project is too big to put here, but as the question says any smaller versions so far don't produce the same error. Sorry, I'm not trying to be unhelpful.

Comment: I assume that `malloc_printerr` and/or `__libc_message` print an error message of some kind - is that the case?

Comment: Yes, they seem to print the whole memory map of the program at the time, mostly involving what libraries are loaded. There seemed to only be a very tiny bit actually pertaining to variables used.

Comment: it might be helpful to see the code for `session_data` and `Session` and from them, constructors, destructors and manipulators only (if they are large classes)

Comment: Well, the only thing I seem to have done is re-compiled with exactly the same code, and I'm glad to say the error has now vanished. I'll keep a close eye on the program, and come back here if it starts again and I still can't work it out.

Thanks for all your help with this.

Comment: Ok, show us the bit of code where you're interacting with mysql and using std::string.  Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: The only interaction with mysql is in the code I added in my edit, as for uses of std::string, they are only used as parameters to functions, except for one `operator=`, but it should be passed by value there I think. Forget what I said about it being fixed, the error has now come back. This is getting more and more strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that your `Session` object got double deleted, OR that it doesn't properly implement the rule-of-(0, 3, 5) and that one of its members got double-deleted (most likely after being shallow copied or assigned).

Comment: Bring out the Valgrind!

Comment: You are correct that I don't implement my own destructor for `Session`, though I didn't think it was necessary as I do not use any pointers which would need special treatment. I'm happy to be told I'm wrong though.

Comment: @user2649502: That would be the "rule of 0" case. You don't need a destructor or any other special member function if all resources are sufficiently managed by members and base classes.